# Save an encrypted String in Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, keychain

I am trying to encrypt a string and save it in the keychain. This is what i have done

```
   //Generate RSA private and public keys
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String: 1024 as AnyObject
    ]
    SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)

    let blockSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey!)
    var messageEncrypted = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: blockSize)
    var messageEncryptedSize = blockSize

    status = SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey!, SecPadding.PKCS1, data, data.characters.count, &messageEncrypted, &messageEncryptedSize)

    let encryptedString = String(data: messageEncrypted, encoding: .utf8)
```

In the last line, I get this error "Cannot convert of type [UInt8] to data".
I basically want to convert messageEncrypted to String so that I can save it in the keychain.
I am using this Keychain Lib - *https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper*
This requires that I enter the data as a String.
Any help will be appreciated.  I understand that saving encrypted data in the keychain might not be the way to go but it's a client requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all is needed is to convert your `messageEncrypted` from `[UInt8]` to `Data` instance, and fortunatelly there is a [fitting initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779744-init) :

```
let encryptedData = Data(bytes: messageEncrypted)
let encryptedString = String(data: encryptedData, encoding: .utf8)
```